# how to give one anchor string to all the checkboxes?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using check boxes tab in DocuSign. I want to put check boxes based on anchor string. for example if I want two check boxes i will give only one anchor string for those check boxes. when I give like this if i check one then all the check boxes are checking. how to give one anchor string for all the check boxes?.

Answer (score 1):

You will want different anchor strings for the different checkboxes. This is because DocuSign has a pre-population feature where tags of the same label will pre-populate the same value (Check or unchecked).[See this Community post here](http://community.docusign.com/t5/Ask-the-Experts-DocuSign-Pros-Q-A-every-Wednesday/Is-there-quot-autofill-quot-capability/ta-p/25255)